# How do I use bitcoind to spend from private key but not store it

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoind, merchant-services

I understand that I need to import a private key in order to spend bitcoins, would it be possible to generate/use an address without storing or the server having the private keys in the server

Ive seen many crypto wallets claim to do this but how would I go about this process

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

For advanced users it is possible to build a raw transaction and sign it in the debug console without having the key imported into your wallet HOWEVER your node needs to be sync'ed at least up to the inputs you intend on spending.

Comment: I see, would it be easier to store and encrypt them in a way i wouldn't have access to it?